# Best method for measure memory usage during matlab operation

Tags: matlab, memory-management

How can I get the memory usage for execution of an instruction in matlab? I look like for something like the `tic` `toc` function.
The problem is that the method must work on windows and on linux.

I try to use this function that use the `whos` command but it doesn't work, it return a wrong value.

I would get the memory usage of this command

```
solution = matrix \ knownTerms;
```

where `solution` and `knownTerms` are two vector.
How can I get the memory used by this operation?

Comment: I don't think there's a platform independent way to do this. On Windows, see the `memory` function. On Linux you should go outside of MATLAB and use the `ps` program.

Comment: What's wrong with the `who` command ? It will return a structure with all your variables. You can check the `bytes` field in order to get the number of bytes allocated by a variable.

Comment: @oro777 Ok, but is not the memory used to solve the problem. Is the memoy used by all variable

Answer (score 2):

If your code is inside a function, you can use the memory mode of the Matlab Profiler to get rough function-level memory usage. Run `profile on -memory`, run your code, and then run `profile report`. If you need to get the memory usage of just that one statement, wrap it in a local function.

Comment: This is not described on the [documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html#f8-618415-option1optionN), are you sure it works across OSes?

Comment: It's undocumented, but it works on Windows and macOS. Dunno about Linux.